# Go Debug not working in GoLand due to Connection refused: no further information

Tags: go, debugging, jetbrains-ide, goland

I trying start a Golang REST API developed with GoLand but I receive this error message:

```
GOROOT=C:\Program Files\Go #gosetup
GOPATH=C:\Users\<myuser>\go #gosetup
"C:\Program Files\Go\bin\go.exe" build -o C:\Users\<myuser>\AppData\Local\Temp\GoLand\___go_build_main_go.exe -gcflags "all=-N -l" C:\Sviluppo\test\testapp\cmd\main.go #gosetup
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\GoLand 2022.3.1\plugins\go-plugin\lib\dlv\windows\dlv.exe" --listen=127.0.0.1:50843 --headless=true --api-version=2 --check-go-version=false --only-same-user=false exec C:\Users\<myuser>\AppData\Local\Temp\GoLand\___go_build_main_go.exe --

Debugger finished with the exit code -1073741510 (0xC000013A: interrupted by Ctrl+C)
```

and

```
Connection refused: no further information: localost/127.0.0.1:50843
```

If I try to start the app without debugging, the app starts correctly.

- My Windows Defender firewall is disabled.
- I tried to reinstall Golang and GoLand but I received the same result.
- I tried with and without the line `127.0.0.1       localhost` in the hosts file.

Everything was working fine until a few days ago.

What can cause this error?

Comment: Do you have another security software except for Windows Defender?

Comment: I don't have other security software. I discovered it's caused by the network I'm connected to. Changing network, it works.