# How to fix an error using debug on Windows

Tags: debugging, goland

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDTqf.png)
As shown in the picture, I get an error when using goland debug.I'm getting errors with debug, but I can run code normally, but not debug.I've tried restarting Goland but it doesn't solve the problem.But restarting Windows seems to fix the problem.
I'm on Windows.How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be similar to [Go Debug not working in GoLand due to Connection refused: no further information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175731/go-debug-not-working-in-goland-due-to-connection-refused-no-further-information) ? Perhaps you have some protection software that blocks the connection, or your network has additional security limitations that are blocking the debugger?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is a strange phenomenon, I have to have the firewall off. And it had been fine before and suddenly became like this. The strange thing is that after half a day it has somehow gotten better. I've restarted my Windows to try to fix this, and while it fixes the problem, it's too much of a hassle.